# Problem with sensor in box2d

Tags: box2d, physics

I have two bodies: one green static sensor (spikes) and one orange dynamic body (brick).

I have bullet and it's a dynamic body too, but with bullet flag set.

My problem is that when the bullet is moving left to right, it sometimes hits the orange brick instead of the spikes and it flies away. There is code to remove the bullet when it hits spikes. How can I make sure it hits the spikes first?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might caused by the "high speed". Remember, most of the in-game movements are not continuous like in real life. The bullet might be fast enough to just pass your spike layer in one frame.

It can be pretty tricky to solve this problem... Please check this: [Continuous Physics Engine's Collision Detection Techniques](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20255/continuous-physics-engines-collision-detection-techniques)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the moving body's definition as a bullet body. Are you still having the problem of skipping the sensor? If so, adjust the scale of the world or frequency of the simulation.